# What should be the structure of this database?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, database-design, relational-database

I want to know what and how should be my structure of my database. I am confused how should i work on.

It is basically for a Car Design.

Requirements:
1) There are many Assembly.
2) In a particular Assembly there are many Parts.
3) In a particular part there can be Materials, Process, Fastener, Tooling table. It describes what and how a part is being made.
4) Materials, Process, Fastener, Tooling all of these have different attributes for each of them.

Here's a spreadsheet that shows some of the relationships.

[image]

I want to know what should be my Database Structure.

I am planning to use VB.NET and Microsoft Access as Database.  Should i change my Database to SQL or any other?

Comment: The design I tried out really dint work well. It had one or the other issues. So still I am confused about the Design. I am unable to link up all the table values together.

Comment: Then let us see one of the designs and show what is wring with it than we might be able to say what is wrong - we won't do the design for you

Comment: Assembly-Assembly_id(PK), Assembly_name

Part-Part_id(PK), Part_name, Assembly_id(FK)

Material- Part_no(FK),Assembly_id(FK),Material_name,Material_cost,...

Process- Part_no(FK),Assembly_id(FK),Process_name,...

Comment: But then realized that if there are two or more materials or process, it wont work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's restate the requirements in a relational format and see if that helps.

- A Car contains one or more Assemblies.
- An Assembly contains one or more Parts.
- An Assembly can be used on one or more Cars.
- A Part contains one or more Materials.
- A Part contains one or more Processes.
- A Part contains one or more Fasteners.
- A Part contains one or more Toolings.
- A Part can be used in one or more Assemblies.
- A Material can be used in one or more Parts.
- A Process can be used in one and only one Part.
- A Fastener can be used in one or more parts.
- A Tooling can be used in one or more parts.

Now, see if you can draw an entity relationship diagram that satisfies these constraints.

What you have are lots of many to many relationships.  I'll draw one of them, and hopefully you can figure out the rest.

```
Car
--------
Car ID
Owner Name
...

Assembly
--------
Assembly ID
Assembly Name
...
```

Now, we know that a Car has one or more Assemblies.  We also know that an Assembly can be used on more than one car.

What we need is another table to tie these two tables together.

```
 Car_Assembly
 -----------
 Car_Assembly ID
 Car ID
 Assembly ID
 Service Date
 ...
```

This table is what allows us to satisfy the many to many relationship between Cars and Assemblies.

From here, you should be able to figure out the other many to many relationships in your database.

Edited to add: Microsoft Access is a relational database.  There are other relational databases, like MySQL, DB2, and Oracle.  SQL is the language that you use to communicate with relational databases.

Comment: Ok I will have a look over it. Thank you for your valuable assistance sir.

Comment: @Gilbert, thanks for pretty much repeating what I already had down.  Extended it a little but that's it.

Answer (score 2):

Without know all the details like what Materials, Processes, etc. it's hard to nail down what would be best but here's one option:

You will have a table for Assembly which will contain and ID for each assembly and a column to track Part_IDs from the Parts table.  You will have a Parts table with each part having it's own unique ID.  Create the Parts table with just Parts info (like serial #, description, etc.) and do the same with Material, Process, Tooling etc.  Then you can create tables to link these together.  So you would have a table that would hold the part_id and the the material_id.  That way, one part can be associated with many materials and more than one part can be associated with the same material.  The same can be done for the other relationships too (Parts-to-processes), (parts-to-tooling) etc.

You don't want to store the Assembly ID in the Parts table because one part could be part of several different assemblies.  A better option would be to have the Assembly table contain a unique ID and maybe name and description info and then have another table track what parts go to an assembly.

So to break it down:  (*EDITED to reflect many-to-many relationships)

```
Assembly         Parts              Material          Parts_Materials   etc
--------         -----              --------          -------           -----
ID       (PK)    Parts_ID (PK)      Material_ID (PK)  Part_ID
Parts_ID (FK)    Attribute1         Attribute1        Material_ID
                 Attribute2         Attribute2        
                 ...               ...
```

As far as a db goes, you might find Access easy to use and get your idea down at first but will want to convert over to a SQL database eventually.

Comment: A Part can contain more than one Material, Process, Fastener, or Tooling.

Comment: Yes, a part may contain more than one material, process, fastenr, tooling into it.

Comment: Is there any way here I can upload a Image which actually shows what exactly I want. Or any other way I can show it to you guys? It will give a better idea.

Comment: I've seen images posted here before so it can be done but haven't done it myself yet.

Comment: http://www.telecast.net.in/test/Untitled.jpg

please refer this you may get the exact idea of what i am talkin about.